# A more colloquial way of comparing A and B than the A のほうがBよりXです pattern?

Tags: comparative-constructions

I want to say that 'A is cheaper than B'.

Genki, the book, would formally suggest:

> A のほうがBよりやすいです.

What would be a more colloquial way to say this?

Answer (score 9):

Just remove the 「です」 which is used basically to make the sentence politer here (丁寧語), and you will have a more familiar version of what you want to express.

You can also remove the 「Bより」 and just say something like :

> Aの方が(もっと)安い

Answer (score 3):

You could also say "やすいのはAだ" or "やすいのはAです". Strictly this translates as "The cheap one is A". Nevertheless, if you have already been discussing the various merits of A and B, then this will give the impression of "the cheaper one is A".

You could even say "やすいのはA"

Answer (score 2):

Colloquially, 〜のほうが is often shortened to 〜のが.

- A**のが**Bより安い
- AよりB**のが**早い etc.